# issue in storing cropped images to aws s3 using jcrop paperclip

Tags: amazon-s3, paperclip, jcrop

i am following  [railscast #182](http://railscasts.com/episodes/182-cropping-images?view=asciicast%20) for image crop and upload.
I am using aws s3 for storing images. Everything works fine according to the documentation. I upload the image, it saves to s3, then I crop it and submit.I see no updation in s3 bucket after croping and the image still is uncropped.
I spent many days in finding solutions and none served the problem completely.
I did little changes in the code compare to railscast doc.

```
 #crop.html.erb
  <br><br>
<% content_for (:head) do %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "jquery.Jcrop" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.Jcrop.min" %>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(function() {
    $('#cropbox').Jcrop({
      onChange: update_crop,
      onSelect: update_crop,
      setSelect: [0, 0, 500, 500],
      aspectRatio: 1
    });
  });

function update_crop(coords) {
  var ratio = <%= current_user.avatar_geometry(:original).width %> / <%= current_user.avatar_geometry(:large).width %>;
  $('#crop_x').val(Math.floor(coords.x * ratio));
  $('#crop_y').val(Math.floor(coords.y * ratio));
  $('#crop_w').val(Math.floor(coords.w * ratio));
  $('#crop_h').val(Math.floor(coords.h * ratio));
}
</script>
<% end %>

  <div class="">
    <%= image_tag current_user.avatar.url(:large), :id => "cropbox" %>
  </div>


<%= form_for(current_user, as: :user, url: registration_path(:user), html: { method: :put, class: "form floating-label" }) do |form| %>
  <% for attribute in [:crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h] %>
    <%= form.hidden_field attribute, :id => attribute %>
  <% end %>
<br>
  <div class="input-field">
    <%= form.label :current_password %> <br />
    <%= form.password_field :current_password, autocomplete: "off",:placeholder => " we need your current password to confirm your changes" %>
  </div>

  <p><%= form.submit "Crop" %></p>

<% end %>
```

layouts

```
    #application.html.erb
<head>
      <title>MY TITLE</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
      <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
      <%= yield(:head)%>
    </head>
```

user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  require "#{Rails.root}/lib/paperclip_processors/cropper.rb"
  if Rails.env == "production"
        S3_CREDENTIALS = {bucket: ENV.fetch('S3_BUCKET_NAME'),
                          access_key_id: ENV.fetch('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
                          secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
                          s3_region: ENV.fetch('AWS_REGION')}

  else
        S3_CREDENTIALS = {bucket: ENV.fetch('S3_BUCKET_NAME'),
                          access_key_id: ENV.fetch('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
                          secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
                          s3_region: ENV.fetch('AWS_REGION')}
  end

  has_attached_file :avatar,
                    styles:{large: "500x500>", medium: "300x300#", thumb: "100x100#" },
                    :processors => [:cropper],
                    default_url: "MY DEFAULT URL",
                    storage:          :s3,
                    s3_credentials:   S3_CREDENTIALS

 validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

  attr_accessor :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h
  after_update :reprocess_avatar, :if => :cropping?

  def cropping?
   !crop_x.blank? && !crop_y.blank? && !crop_w.blank? && !crop_h.blank?
  end

  def avatar_geometry(style = :original)
    @geometry ||= {}
    avatar_path = (avatar.options[:storage] == :s3) ? avatar.url(style) : avatar.path(style)
    @geometry[style] ||= Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(avatar_path)
end

private
  def reprocess_avatar
   avatar.reprocess!
  end
```

lib/paperclip_processors/cropper.rb

```
module Paperclip
  class Cropper < Thumbnail
    def transformation_command
      if crop_command
        crop_command + super.join(' ').sub(/ -crop \S+/, '').split(' ') # super returns     an array like this: ["-resize", "100x", "-crop", "100x100+0+0", "+repage"]
      else
        super
      end
    end

    def crop_command
      target = @attachment.instance
      if target.cropping?
        ["-crop", "#{target.crop_w}x#{target.crop_h}+#{target.crop_x}+#{target.crop_y}"]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

GEMFILE

```
gem "paperclip", "~> 4.3"
gem 'aws-sdk','< 2.0'
gem 'materialize-sass'
gem 'devise'
```

Thanx in Advance